# How Can I add OpenTLD into OpenCV 3.4.1 and VS2015?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I uploaded all of opencv libraries by Cmake for Visual Studio 2015 but i didn't add OpenTLD into OpenCV. Do you know how can I add it. May you describe step by step.

[openTLD on vs2015 screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8t95.png)
[CMake screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7SRJ.png)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Well, have you googled for tutorials or examples?

Comment: Yes of course I have been searching since three days but I failed to find regarding add OpenTLD